# NSForm cells not displaying correctly

Tags: xcode, macos, nsform

I'm adding an NSForm to an NSTabView in IB and everything looks fine (top picture). When I launch the app and goto the tab with the NSForm the form text fields look like the picture on the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I vaguely remember (WWDC videos?) that NSForm is not supported for auto layout. Just use text fields and labels, or revert to springs and struts.

Comment: Over 2 years on and this bug still exists.  A pity as this control would be good if it worked.

Comment: @Andrew this is ridiculous. I understand now why OSX developers say iOS is easier to develop for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just did what Nicholas suggested and used text fields and labels. Works great!